# Is there a limit on the number of MOKs we can write to firmware?

Tags: drivers, uefi, secure-boot, firmware

**IF YOU ARE NOT SURE, PLEASE DO GIVE YOUR THOUGHTS ON THIS**

After installing Ubuntu, if we install a graphics driver for dedicated graphics card then we need to enroll a MOK to the firmware. As far as I understand, the key I enroll should go into the ROM. I generally keep installing and uninstalling Linux. When I remove the Linux partition, the MOK should still be there in the firmware according to me. And when I install Linux again then if I generate a new MOK, then it would also go into the firmware.

Can I OR should I do this multiple times without any issues. I feel, like this, there would be a lot of garbage MOKs in the firmware.

What should be done in such a case? Should the MOK be deleted before removing Linux? If yes, then how? If we don't remove the MOK before removing Linux, is there a way to remove it outside it?

I've seen this post : [Is it possible to delete an enrolled key using mokutil without the original .der file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805152/is-it-possible-to-delete-an-enrolled-key-using-mokutil-without-the-original-der)
But I don't exactly get how it works.

I think I don't clearly understand where the key is stored.

I want to understand this MOK concept and know how to deal with it in case of a machine where I may be continuously removing and installing Linux and each time I'll install the graphics driver too.